# Compress-7Zip : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by path

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I have added these lines to my script:

```
$fzip=Get-Item -Path $movefolder'*'
$name = -join($fzip, ".7z");
echo $name
Compress-7Zip -Path $fzip -ArchiveFileName $name
```

I am getting this error

```
Compress-7Zip : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by path.method is not supported.
At C:\Scripts\logsbackup.ps1:28 char:21
+ Compress-7Zip -Path $fzip -ArchiveFileName $name
+                     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Compress-7Zip], ParameterBindingException
```

Comment: do you need to 7zip all subfolders of `$movefolder` directory to multiple 7zip archives?, if so you need some sort of for loop because the command `Compress-7Zip` accepts a string for `path` and `ArchiveFileName` and you pass both as array

Comment: What's the meaning of `$movefolder'*'` ?? What folder do you want to zip ?

Comment: I have put the path on movefolder

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Compress-7Zip -Path ($Fzip.parent[0].Fullname) -ArchiveFileName $name
```

It takes the parent path of the first object in your array and selects the property "Fullname" which is the path